# How do I use panelize in Midnight Commander? I want to know since this is a way to do a recursive chmod on selected files and directories

Tags: mc

I know I can use chmod and advanced chmod but they do not offer me a way to **recursively** change permissions on the filed and folders. Panelize seems to be able to do that. However I seem not to get any results if I select files with Ctrl-t and then choose panelize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the command "Paneli**z**e" in **L**eft/**R**ight menus does. It's not documented and I've never made it to work.

The only working "Paneli**z**e" I know is in "Find file": <kbd>F9</kbd> | **C**ommand | **F**ind file. Find, get a list of files, press "Paneli**z**e", get a panel full of found files, work with the files.

If you just need to run `chmod`/`chown` on a few directories recursively without excludes it's faster and simpler (for me) to run the commands in the command line. Tag (select) directories and run (for example):

```
chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX %s
chown -R root.root %s
```

`%s` will be replaces by the list of tagged directories/files or the current one if none is tagged.

Comment: Thanks. Using %s is just what I needed! This will come handy in other situations as well.