# Chmod Recursive in Midnight Commander

Tags: linux, mc

Is there Recursive option for `chmod` and `chown` in Midnight Commander? 
Chmod, chown and advanced chown do not make changes to the files within directories.

Comment: Looks like, no, there is no such option: https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3109

Comment: You can use "Panelize" to find files recursively and apply "chmod"/"chown"/"Advanced chown" to all files in the panel. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61794358/7976758